# How to enable forecast option in PowerBI analytics?

Tags: powerbi, forecasting, linechart

[image]
[image]

Hi everyone,

I'm finding the forecast option under analytics but I couldn't find it. There is only one series of data in my line chart but the forecast option still not available, may I know what should I do in order to enable to forecast option? the screenshot below is my table in case needed:

[image]

Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

### Edited

[image]

Comment: Edited my screenshot

Comment: Show the date field in the X axis, not the date hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what do you mean by show the date field? I added another screenshot in my question under Edited session, not sure is that what you want to see

Comment: Second screenshot, under Axis, right click `Date` field and click on `Date` (while currently `Date Hierarchy` is the selected one).

Comment: Thanks Andrey, it works now, still new to PowerBI